# Systemd + PM2 issue - PM2 path gives error

Tags: node.js, npm, systemd, pm2, systemctl

A node.js app which runs successfully via 'npm start' and via PM2 (`pm2 start npm -- start`), does not run as a systemctl service.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

`journalctl -xe`

```
Jul 16 18:30:05 test.com systemd[7420]: systems.bbb.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Jul 16 18:30:05 test.com systemd[7420]: systems.bbb.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/pm2 start npm -- start: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /usr/local/bin/pm2 start npm -- start could not be executed
```

```
which pm2
/usr/local/bin/pm2
```

An env file is specified in the systemd file, a configuration which works ok for Go based services.
The systems.bbb.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Systems backend service
After=syslog.target network.target network-online.target
Requires=mongod.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/root/bbb/git-repos/bbb
ExecStart="/usr/local/bin/pm2 start npm -- start"
Restart=on-failure
User=root
EnvironmentFile=/root/bbb/git-repos/bbb/env
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the exact same issue, right now…

Answer (score 0):

pm2 is an app that runs with npm.you cannot tell the pm2 start the npm.

pm2 looks for the entry point of your project.

try something like this :

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Comment: Thanks, but `pm2 start npm -- start` does work. It's a feature of pm2 for npm. Here's an overview:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-use-npm-to-start-your-app